# How to process salesforce error files in informatica cloud

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics-di

we are integrating data into salesforce from Hive database source using informatica cloud.
But when we use SFDC standard API,its generating error file with all rejected records.

Here we have to re-process the error file to make sure all source records loaded into salesforce. The error file will be generated in unix box
path: \apps\Data_Integration_Server\data\error.

The file name will be in the format _timestamp.csv. ex: s_mtt_0103YB0Z000000000012_3_26_2020_12_21_standard_error.csv

can anyone pls help me i didn't find answers in Informatica cloud platform community.

Comment: can you not create a list file like this `s_mtt_standard_error_list.txt` by using `ls -1 s_mtt_*standard_error.csv > s_mtt_standard_error_list.txt` and use it in session indirect file  list. You need to use a shell script if you have many files else you can use pre session command.

Comment: Hi Koushik thank you. files will be created for each run and i need script to trim timestamp and process the files using indirect method after processing the file we need to archive it

Comment: you dont have to trim anything. You can put them into list file using pattern `ls -1 s_mtt_*standard_error.csv`